# Limiting Google street view to extent on OpenLayers 2?

Tags: google-maps-api, openlayers-2

I would like to be able to limit the Google street view area in my map to to 500m radius from where the panoramic street view starts ( this is where the user clicked the mouse on the map).

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to add restrictedExtent to map options.

Comment: I want to restroct the street view to 500m raidus from point clicked but not the entire map (which is restricted on country level )